# qt is not linked correctly when building with cmake and conan

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cmake, conan

I'm learning C++ and Qt and to start off I'm trying to build an application with QT.

I'm using cmake to build, and conan for the package manager.
By following the [Qt guide for Conan](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_6_from_Git) I've got a build, but when executing it this is what I get:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>



int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

```
matteo@MacBook-Pro-de-matteo build % export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
matteo@MacBook-Pro-de-matteo build % ./bin/myapp          
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3" since plugins are disabled in static builds
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

zsh: abort      ./bin/myapp
```

Info:

```
matteo@MacBook-Pro-de-matteo everywhere % conan -v
Conan version 1.44.0

matteo@MacBook-Pro-de-matteo everywhere % cmake --version
cmake version 3.22.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
qtbase/6.2.2@qt/everywhere
qt-conan-common/6.2@qt/everywhere
qtdeclarative/6.2.2@qt/everywhere


[generators]
cmake
```

Library build via by executing the following command (MacOS):

```
conan install ./conanfile.txt --build=missing --profile=conan/qtprofiles/macos-universal-clang --update --generator=VirtualBuildEnv -r qt
```

I've changed `macos-universal-clang`'s compiler version to 13 to make it match with the compiler version, otherwise it didn't compile:

`macos-universal-clang`:

```
[settings]
    os=Macos
    os.version=11.0
    arch=x86_64
    compiler=apple-clang
    compiler.version=13.0
    compiler.libcxx=libc++
    build_type=RelWithDebInfo
[options]
qtbase:release=yes
qtbase:shared=yes
qtbase:nomake=examples;tests
qtbase:force_debug_info=yes
qtbase:separate_debug_info=yes
qtbase:framework=yes
qtbase:cmake_args_qtbase='-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="x86_64;arm64" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DODBC_ROOT=/usr/local/opt/libiodbc'
*:cmake_args_leaf_module=""
[build_requires]
[env]
```

the library is found when compiling:

```
matteo@MacBook-Pro-de-matteo myxconfig % ./activate.sh                   
matteo@MacBook-Pro-de-matteo myxconfig % cmake -S . -B out/build  
-- Conan: Adjusting output directories
-- Conan: Using cmake global configuration
-- Conan: Adjusting default RPATHs Conan policies
-- Conan: Adjusting language standard
-- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: .../out/build
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ..../out/build

cd out/build

matteo@MacBook-Pro-de-matteo build % make                   

[100%] Built target myxconfig
matteo@MacBook-Pro-de-matteo myxconfig % echo $?
0
```

What's wrong?

### Update

I've made it work by statically linking the cocoa plugin into the executable:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtPlugin>
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QCocoaIntegrationPlugin)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

This was the repo I got inspired from: https://github.com/siavashk/qt5-static-hello-world

Still, as a freshman I'm still asking myself:

- How can I avoid to bundle it and make it work anyway, in case the OS in which is run has the lib installed?
- A short explication about what Qt calls "plugins" (with some reference to the doc) would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

This message is not about linking but about Qt runtime no able to find files:

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""

Either set environment variable:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/me/.conan/data/qt/5.12.0/repo/stable/package/f3d861c7053b683d8cf8fcd66b11dc1dee351153/plugins
```

or

```
QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/me/.conan/data/qt/5.12.0/repo/stable/package/f3d861c7053b683d8cf8fcd66b11dc1dee351153/plugins
```

From experience one of those should work depending on Qt build but mind your local system paths. The above is from Linux project and we create similar for other platforms. So, our installer creates launch script file `start.sh` as follows:

```
QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/me/.conan/data/qt/5.12.0/repo/stable/package/f3d861c7053b683d8cf8fcd66b11dc1dee351153/plugins
/home/me/progPath/bin/qtProgram
```

Mind that the above is not a rule and may depend on installation setup.